# jQuery dynamically adding form fields calculating wrong total

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, onchange

First all; sorry if my question is irrelevant. Because i'm new on `javascript` and `jquery`.

I have a form and has some piece inputs, and selects dynamically creating with `jquery`. But somehow i cant calculate total value of a row
My code structure looks like;

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Hizmet Ekle</h5>
        <br>
        <div id="services-cont">
            <div class="form-group  m-form__group row" id="services-inner">
                <fieldset id="add-services">
                    <div id="services" class="col-lg-12"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="m-form__group form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="btn btn btn-sm btn-brand m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--pill m-btn--wide add-service">
                        <span>
                            <i class="la la-plus"></i>
                            <span>Ekle</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript for adding new form values

```
// Adding new service container with form inputs
$('.add-service').on('click',function(){
    var current = $('.new-service').length;
    var partCount = current + 1;  
    var template = 
    '<div class="form-group m-form__group row align-items-center new-service" style="display:none;">\
        <div class="col-md-4">\
            <div class="form-group m-form__group">\
                <label for="services['+partCount+']">Hizmet</label>\
                <div class="m-input-icon m-input-icon--right">\
                    <select id="services['+partCount+']" name="services[]" data-id="'+partCount+'" class="form-control m-input m-input--air m-input--pill"></select>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="d-md-none m--margin-bottom-10"></div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="col-md-2">\
            <div class="form-group m-form__group">\
                <label for="unit_price['+partCount+']">Birim Fiyat</label>\
                <div class="m-input-icon m-input-icon--right">\
                    <input name="unit_price['+partCount+']" type="text" class="form-control m-input m-input--pill m-input--air" disabled>\
                    <span class="m-input-icon__icon m-input-icon__icon--right"><span><i class="la la-try"></i></span></span>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="d-md-none m--margin-bottom-10"></div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="col-md-2">\
            <div class="form-group m-form__group">\
                <label for="quantity['+partCount+']">Miktar Seçimi</label>\
                <div class="input-group m-input-group m-input-group--pill">\
                    <input name="quantity['+partCount+']" type="number" class="form-control m-input m-input--pill m-input--air" placeholder="Örn: 5 Adet">\
                    <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">Adet</span></div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="d-md-none m--margin-bottom-10"></div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="col-md-2">\
            <div class="form-group m-form__group">\
                <label for="unit_price['+partCount+']">Toplam Fiyat</label>\
                <div class="m-input-icon m-input-icon--right">\
                    <input name="total_price['+partCount+']" type="text" class="form-control m-input m-input--pill m-input--air" disabled>\
                    <span class="m-input-icon__icon m-input-icon__icon--right"><span><i class="la la-try"></i></span></span>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="d-md-none m--margin-bottom-10"></div>\
        </div>\
        <div class="col-md-1">\
            <div class="btn-sm btn btn-danger m-btn m-btn--icon m-btn--pill del-new-service">\
                <span>\
                    <i class="la la-trash-o"></i>\
                    <span>Kaldır</span>\
                </span>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
    $('#services').append(template); 
    $('#services').find(".new-service:last").slideDown("fast");   
    loadServices();
});
$("#services").on('click', '.del-new-service', function() {
    $(this).closest(".new-service").slideUp("fast", function() { 
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
});
```

Javascript For Calculating Values

```
// Calculating values
var count;
var unitPrice;
var taxValue;
var unitPriceWithTax
var calculateUnitPrice = function(){
    $("#services").on('change', 'select[name="services[]"]', function() {
        dataId = $(this).data('id');
        unitPrice = parseFloat($(this).find(':selected').data('price'));
        taxValue = parseFloat($(this).find(':selected').data('tax'));
        unitPriceWithTax = parseFloat($(this).find(':selected').data('total'));
        // Append Unit Price
        $("input[name='unit_price["+dataId+"]']").val(unitPrice);
        // Append Total Price
        var quantity;
        $("input[name='quantity["+dataId+"]']").on('change', function(){
            totalPrice = unitPrice * parseFloat($(this).val());
            $("input[name='total_price["+dataId+"]']").val(totalPrice);
        });
        console.log(dataId);
        // Total Units
        console.log(unitPrice);
    });
}
```

I think something wrong with my calculate function because of `select on change method`. When i add multiple values and change randomly a `select value` it's calculating wrong row. I'm lost in here.

Example Screenshot Here;

[image]

**Any help greatly appricated.**

Comment: Why do you add a new `change` handler to `"input[name='quantity["+dataId+"]']"` on every change of "its" `select[name="services[]"]` ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Andreas thx for fast response because of quantity must change value by user. How can i detect quantity value changed?

Comment: _"How can I ..."_ - With _one_ `change` or `input` event handler, but you add one for every change of the select.

Comment: @Andreas should i use selector for input groups parent div to trigger change event?

Comment: @Andreas perfect point for me. You changed my mind about triggering event (: Thx so much.